# Translation of "neither team played well"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> Neither Team A or Team B played well.

could be translated as

> Weder Team A noch Team B hat gut gespielt.

(is it "hat" and not "haben", similar to in English?)

What about

> Neither team played well. / Neither of the teams played well.

How would we express "neither" in this situation?

Comment: No, you'd use the plural here, i.e.: "Weder A noch B haben gut gut gespielt." That said, "Keines der Teams hat ... " would also work.

Comment: Regarding "hat" vs "haben". The short answer: **both** are correct. See [this article](http://canoo.net/blog/2011/02/10/weder-sie-noch-er-ist-sind/) and [here for a summary](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html?lang=en#Anchor-Mit-14210).

Comment: *Keine Seite spielte gut* works, because *Seite* ‘side’ implies that there are exactly two of them, which *kein+* doesn’t.

Comment: Am I the only one who would use "Mannschaft" instead of "Team" in German?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colloquially, you might say:

> Keines der beiden Teams hat gut gespielt.

However, if your context demands that the teams be specified in the same sentence, the suggestion you've made works well.

Comment: What exactly is colloquial about this? I find it to be proper high German, especially with the "eines"

Comment: @emanuel Colloquial doesn't necessarily mean dialectal. Here, I meant that it is a less formal option than giving the two teams by name as in the "Weder A noch B" formulation.

Answer (score 2):

In German there's no equivalent to the determiner *neither*, which limits the amount of objects to exactly two instances.

That is, you need to translate "neither team" as "Keines der **beiden** Teams", as [suggested in the other answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/13542/1224). If you'd only say "Kein Team" or "Keines der Teams", it would be unclear how many teams were playing.

Of course, you could express the same thing by saying "Both teams didn't play well" which is "Beide Teams haben nicht gut gespielt".
I dare to say that this is more common; however, I don't have any proof.